# Renaming a File in a different path

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I tried renaming a fie with Follwoing Syntax:

```
int iRenameXML,iRenameXMLErr;
iRenameXML = rename("D:\Debug\CurrentServers.xml",
                             "D:\Debug\CurrentServersssss.xml");
iRenameXMLErr = GetLastError();
```

But this Get me [GLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) 2 ,ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

Is there any other way I can change tha name of a file at other location.

I do not think chdir will be a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need do double backslash the \

```
int iRenameXML,iRenameXMLErr;
iRenameXML = rename("D:\\Debug\\CurrentServers.xml",
                             "D:\\Debug\\CurrentServersssss.xml");
iRenameXMLErr = GetLastError();
```

Comment: Thanks . Forgetting escape sequence :) I don't want to do this agn

Comment: @Subhen You're welcome. I forget too when going back to C++ from C#, in C# I can do `@"D:\Debug\CurrentServers.xml"` and not worry about escape sequences!

Answer (score 2):

See ["[15.16] Why can't I open a file in a different directory such as "..\test.dat"?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.16) in the [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite).